# Subprocess.Popen stuck in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am calling a command executable in Ubuntu using:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(commandarray,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         bufsize=0, close_fds=ON_POSIX, env=os.environ.copy())
```

However, when I run this, it is stuck at this step. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I think sharing the content of `commandarray` would be useful

Comment: the commandarray looks like: `['mytool', '--verbose', '-s', u'12346', '-y', '/home/myuser/.mytool/config.txt']`

Comment: The path to mytool has been added to .bashrc.

Comment: If you write the code in a file and run  `strace python file.py`, you should be able to see at which system call it is stuck.

Comment: how do you mean stuck?

Comment: Why do you use `bufsize=0, close_fds=ON_POSIX, env=os.environ.copy()`?